# Compare column A with column B and return minimum value in column A in Column C

Tags: excel

Here is my table.  I want to return the minimum value from column A in column C only if the values in Column B are equal.

```
   A       B           C
1  Price   Category    Lowest Price Per Category
2  240      19  
3  231      19          231
4  233      19  
5  450      12  
6  438      12  
7  425      12          425
8  674      33  
9  675      33   
10 671      33          671
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `SUBTOTAL`function and use this formula in the column for lowest:

```
=IF(A2=SUBTOTAL(5;$A$2:$A$4);A2;"")
```

You would have to manually adjust the locked range ($A$2:$A$4) for every group though so that it matches the range for the group.

Or if your happy with getting the min value for each group on a separate row under every group you could just mark the two columns (including header row) and use the `Subtotal`button on the Data tab set like in this image:

[image]

Then the result would look something like this:

```
Price Category
240   19
231   19
233   19
231   19 Min
450   12
438   12
425   12
425   12 Min
674   33
675   33
671   33
671   33 Min
231   Grand Min
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula in C2 copied down

`=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"<"&A2),"",A2)`

`COUNTIFS` here counts rows where the category matches and the price is lower than the current row. If there is no such row then the current row price must be lowest for that category and the price is returned.

If there are tied lowest prices within any category then they will all be shown